# How to pass an argument passed to a bashrc function?

Tags: bash, shell, parameters, arguments, parameter-passing

I added a custom command to bash and can't pass arguments into it

I have a bnpmf.sh file in `/usr/bin` which specifies the bnpmf function

Now I source the bnpmf.sh file from `/etc/bash.bashrc` with source /usr/bin/bnpmf.sh

When I iterate over the arguments in the function, by arguments I mean `shell: bnpmf arg1 arg2` ,they simply do not show up whatsoever, which is incredibly weird.

I use `while [[ $@ -gt 0 ]] do` to iterate over the arguments

How do I get these arguments recognized in my function

Comment: Function arguments are in `$1`, `$2`, etc. just like script arguments.

Comment: The number of arguments is `$#`, not `$@`.

Comment: Any shell scripting tutorial should explain all of this.

Comment: You need to post your code. Also, check it first at shellcheck.net.

Comment: To iterate over the arguments, you use `for argument in "$@"; do ...`. Inside the loop body, the respective argument is then stored in the variable `argument`.